# Reinstalled Ubuntu, i use separate /home partition, can't launch apps from previous install

Tags: home

I reinstalled Ubuntu after boot broke when updating to 18.10, since i had my home in a separate partition i thought i was not gonna lose my apps, mainly steam and it's games, but the previous apps don't appear on GNOME and when i try to launch steam from a desktop shortcut it gives me an error, when launching through nautilus it says i'm missing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most apps are not installed in your home dir. The config files and app data are stored in your home dir.

So in theory you could

copy your home dir to homebac: cp -r /home /homebac 

then reinstall all of your apps

then move homebac to home: mv -r /homebac /home

Comment: Hm, i get it, so this way i could keep the games, thanks.